# bootBuildImage fails with two spring modules in my gradle project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am currently developing a multi module project. I basically have, very oversimplified, a backend and a frontend app. Both use Spring Boot 2.6.1 with Java 11. I use gradle 6.8

I am currently trying to figure out how to get two images to build with the bootBuildImage tasks of the two modules. I figured it was a good starting point to get the projects to build their image separately, before building both of them at the same time. However, this does not seem to work.

This is my project setup:

[image]

I currently want to build the data-service image. This is its' build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.1"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    id("net.linguica.maven-settings") version "0.5"
}

group = rootProject.group
version = rootProject.version
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = "gg-repo"
        setUrl("CENSORED")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":shared"))


    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.2")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")


    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.6.1")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And this is the error I get.

```
> Task :shared:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :shared:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :shared:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :shared:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :data-service:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :data-service:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :data-service:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :data-service:bootJarMainClassName UP-TO-DATE
> Task :data-service:bootJar UP-TO-DATE
6 actionable tasks: 6 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':data-service:bootBuildImage' (type 'BootBuildImage').
  - In plugin 'org.springframework.boot' type 'org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootBuildImage' property 'archiveFile' has @Input annotation used on property of type 'RegularFileProperty'.
    
    Reason: A property of type 'RegularFileProperty' annotated with @Input cannot determine how to interpret the file.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Annotate with @InputFile for regular files.
      2. Annotate with @InputFiles for collections of files.
      3. If you want to track the path, return File.absolutePath as a String and keep @Input.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#incorrect_use_of_input_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'org.springframework.boot' type 'org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootBuildImage' property 'jar' has @Input annotation used on property of type 'RegularFileProperty'.
    
    Reason: A property of type 'RegularFileProperty' annotated with @Input cannot determine how to interpret the file.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Annotate with @InputFile for regular files.
      2. Annotate with @InputFiles for collections of files.
      3. If you want to track the path, return File.absolutePath as a String and keep @Input.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#incorrect_use_of_input_annotation for more details about this problem.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
00:51:37: Task execution finished 'bootBuildImage'.
```

I cannot find anything about this error online, so I hope you excuse the overly general title. As far as I understand the error it does not know in which file to store the image in? What is going on here?

Comment: I doubt the plugins for Spring Boot 2.6 are compatible with Gradle 8. Downgrade gradle.

Comment: Oh... thats interesting. In IntelliJ and my gradles.properties file I told gradle to be on version 6.8 I will investigate that!

Comment: Well unless you are using the wrapper (`gradlew` instead of `gradle`) that is going to be ignored.

Comment: I changed the distribution url in the gradle-wrapper.properties to math the 6.8 url: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8-bin.zip`. Also the settings in intellij say "use gradle from gradle-wrapper.properties". Therefore I thought that this was fitting, but apparently it wasnt...

Comment: Executing gradlew :data-service:bootBuildImage does not throw this error, but at least proceeds to compiling and then working on the image. So this is definitely an IDE problem

Comment: Due to a problem with the gradle sync with my IDE it did not update the settings so it would take the downgraded gradle. I updated my IDE, therefore basically reinstalling which fixed the problem on the spot. After all, the version was just too new, so that solved my problem. Much love <3